# Weird character is appearing while formatting the code in VS Code on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm using VS Code on my Macbook pro with OS as Catalina. The formatting of code was used to work whenever I used to press the keys like Shift + Option + F key. But now after a while it stopped working. If I press the same keys then I get a underscore like character (_) instead of my code getting formatted. Please help me as I'm stuck sine long time. I tried a lot Googling the solution but did not find anything about this weird character upon doing the code formatting. Refer attached screenshot, at line# 7, you see that character (which seems like underscore)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 6 months but, better later than never.

Try adding a different input source in `System preferences` > `Keyboard`. I was having the same issue when I changed my input source from spanish (Latin American) to `ABC - Extended` and after trying `ABC` it worked fine.